# Accentuated upper letters in java

Tags: java, file

I wrote a java program in Netbeans to modify some files. The entry files are UTF8. The program copies the entry file and modifies or adds some things :

```
....
StringBuffer modifiedLine = new StringBuffer();
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(writingFile);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  if(idNeeded) {
      modifiedLine.append(String.valueOf(i));
      modifiedLine.append(";");
  }
  modifiedLine.append(modifyDatesInLine(line, oracleDates));
  bw.write( modifiedLine.toString() + ";" + .....);
  bw.newLine();
  i++;
  modifiedLine = new StringBuffer();
}
...
```

it is quite classical.

The problem is that the generated files, for upper letter (not lower) with accents displays something wrong... xc3? the letter in I with two points on it.

so for à, é, è, î ... it is fine, but for I trema not (I dont even know how to type upper letters with accent but somebody did)

Thank you

Comment: Is your JVM's default charset UTF8? If not, you should set it explicitly when creating the readers and writers. (And even if it is, you probably should set it explicitly, so that the code continues to work even if the default changes)

Comment: If I write : System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));, I have UTF-8. If it was not UTF8, the other letters would not appear correctly I think as my entry files are utf8

Comment: What exactly are you seeing in place of the accented ‘I’ that you expected to see?

Comment: xc3? with Notepad ++, the xc3 is with a black background like when you open a word file with notepad ++